# Is autocorrelation an indication of Non Stationary Series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, sarimax

I have time series data and it has following ACF plot

[image]

I read [The data should be stationary](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/time-series/how-to/autocorrelation/before-you-start/data-considerations/)

"The data is non-stationary when there is a large spike at lag 1 that slowly decreases over several lags. If you see this pattern, you should difference the data before you attempt to identify a model. To difference the data, use differences. Once you difference the data, obtain another autocorrelation plot."

Adf test telling me the data is stationary as its p values is less than 0.05.

For stationary series , I read many places that "A stationary time series has a mean, variance, and autocorrelation function that are essentially constant through time."

do we really need to have constant autocorrelation for each lag for data to be stationary?

Based on Mauritis response here i am attaching graph highlighted with seasonal region[image]

Comment: As I explain in the comments to my answer, the highlighted regions in the data are *not* seasonal patterns. The underlying data generating process is a simple AR(1) model without any seasonality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is autocorrelation an indication of Non Stationary Series

The short answer is no.

---

To demonstrate, let's consider a stationary AR(1) process: I'm using R here to simulate data and plot the ACF.

```r
set.seed(2020)
ts <- arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.8), n = 100)
plot(ts)
```

[image]

```r
acf(ts)
```

[image]

Notice how the sample autocorrelation tapers off; to be specific, the ACF decreases with *phi^h* where *h* is the lag and *phi* is the slope in the AR(1) model (here *phi = 0.8*).

Comment: don't you see any seasonal pattern in your simulated data - i uploaded your graph in my original question

Comment: @user172500 No. By design, these are *not* seasonal patterns. Time series data can be tricky to interpret and the eye can be deceiving. Even more, not all time series data with cyclic patterns are seasonal, see e.g. [Rob Hyndman's section on stationarity and differencing](https://otexts.com/fpp2/stationarity.html).

Comment: @user172500 The key answer (and explanation) to your question is that autocorrelation does not imply a non stationary process. As I show, an AR(1) process has a very well defined autocorrelation trend with increasing lag.

Comment: I agreed but these things are puzzling me https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372145/adf-test-showing-stationary-for-a-non-stationary-series